# Passing Multiple Values to a PHP Shopping Cart

Tags: php, mysql, post, store, cart

First of all, this is my first PHP store, so if I seem a bit daft, I apologize.

Short form: How can I pass a set of values to `$_SESSION` variables for a PHP shopping cart, without using a separate form for each item on a page?

Here's the situation. I'm trying to create a store. The products on each page will be called from a MySQL database, and organized by cost. This is all working perfectly.

The problem I'm running into involves the item options. Some of these items, like ballcaps, T-shirts, and other assorted goods, will have multiple sizes/colors. The way I have this organized now is that each entry in the MySQL table that matches the criteria is output into its own form, with options for size and color, if applicable. The issue I'm having with this is that while I can apparently post these to another page, I cannot seem to assign them to a variable.

I would love to do away with the forms entirely, and use a hyperlink like this:
    Add to cart
but I'm not sure it's an option, ad I'd need to pass the values of the size and color on some items.

I know this has been done before, and often, but I can't seem to get Google to help me out here. Any advice/tips/tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my current code, using the multiple forms method I thought would be good when I started:

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
  echo "<form method='post' action='addcart.php'>";
  echo "<tr><td><img width='100' width='100' src='itemImages/" . $row['itemIMG'] . "'/></td>
  <td>" . $row['itemNAME'] . "</td>
  <td><p id='description'>" . $row['itemDESC'] . "</p></td> <td>";
  //Color dropdown population happens here
  if($row["itemCOL1"] != ' '){
    echo "<select name=colors>";
    $finished = 'false';
    $i = '0';
    $colrow = mysql_fetch_array($coldata);
    while($finished != 'true'){
       if($colrow[$i] != ' '){  
         echo "<option value=" . $colrow[$i] . ">" . $colrow[$i] . "</option>";
         $i++;
    } else {
      echo "</select>";
      $finished='true';
    }
   }
  }
//Size option dropdown handled here
if($row['itemHSIZ'] != "N"){
  echo "<select name=prodSizes>";
  echo "<option value=X-Small>X-Small  </option>";
  //Sizes omitted for brevity
  echo "</select>";
  }
echo "<input type='hidden' name='prodName' value='" . $row['itemNAME'] . "' />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /></form>";
};
//...and above here.
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you can move the form open and form close outside of your while loop to have all the items be in one form, and thus one post:

```
<?php
  echo "<form method='post' action='addcart.php'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
  echo "<tr><td><img width='100' width='100' src='itemImages/" . $row['itemIMG'] . "'/></td>
  <td>" . $row['itemNAME'] . "</td>
  <td><p id='description'>" . $row['itemDESC'] . "</p></td> <td>";
  //Color dropdown population happens here
  if($row["itemCOL1"] != ' '){
    echo "<select name=colors>";
    $finished = 'false';
    $i = '0';
    $colrow = mysql_fetch_array($coldata);
    while($finished != 'true'){
       if($colrow[$i] != ' '){  
         echo "<option value=" . $colrow[$i] . ">" . $colrow[$i] . "</option>";
         $i++;
    } else {
      echo "</select>";
      $finished='true';
    }
   }
  }
//Size option dropdown handled here
if($row['itemHSIZ'] != "N"){
  echo "<select name=prodSizes>";
  echo "<option value=X-Small>X-Small  </option>";
  //Sizes omitted for brevity
  echo "</select>";
  }
echo "<input type='hidden' name='prodName' value='" . $row['itemNAME'] . "' />";
};
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /></form>";
//...and above here.
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Let me know if this isn't what you meant!

Comment: I tried (briefly) to do that, but then I would need a way of separating each item's color and size, along with the Submit buttons. I couldn't think of an easy way to do that.

Comment: If you look at the last echo, I brought the submit button outside of the while loop too. This will solve your problem of having multiple submit buttons.

Comment: What is your issue with separating item colors and sizes? Is it that you won't know which one is selected? One way to solve this would be to add a radio so that they can select which item they want. You could also assume they want an item if both the color and size are selected.

Comment: Essentially, the job requires the sizes and colors to be a dropdown. When I tried to make this one giant form, all of the color and size values from all products get posted. It's basically to be like a standard store with options. I may have solved the problem, though. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can go about it both using JavaScript. You can use JavaScript to make ajax calls to a php script using onclick events attached to your add to cart button/link or you could use JavaScript to add parameters to your add to cart link when options are selected.

Does that make sense?

PS don't use id on the p tag like that. You want to keep id values unique.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using JavaScript, though I may have to. It does make perfect sense, it's just another language I'd have to dip into on the fly.